# Listbox values not being stored to the database in Classic ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am working on a Classic ASP page.
Earlier there was a checkbox list in the page which I have changed to a multi select listbox. Now after I changed it to multi select listbox the selected values are not getting saved into the database which was saving when it was a checkbox list.

The below is code from my html page....

```html
<div class="fields options secondary-category">
  <legend>Secondary Category</legend>
  <p class="description">You may select up to two secondary categories in which you would like to be considered for an award (please hold the control key to select two categories).</p>
  <select id="AwardsSecondaryCatagory" class="input-listbox" type="listbox" name="AwardsSecondaryCatagory" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option>Select an option</option>
    <option name="financialexcellence" value="Financial Excellence">Financial Excellence</option>
    <option name="operationalexcellence" value="Operational Excellence">Operational Excellence</option>
    <option name="employeeexcellence" value="Employee Excellence">Employee Excellence</option>
    <option name="customerexcellence" value="Customer Excellence">Customer Excellence</option>
    <option name="Innovation" value="Innovation">Innovation</option>
    <option name="Transformation" value="Transformation">Transformation</option>
  </select>
  <!--
  <div class="field opt">
    <input id="financialexcellence" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Financial Excellence" name="financialexcellence">
    <label for="financialexcellence">Financial Excellence</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field opt">
    <input id="operationalexcellence" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Opertional Excellence" name="operationalexcellence">
    <label for="operationalexcellence">Operational Excellence</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field opt">
    <input id="employeeexcellence" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Employee Execellence" name="employeeexcellence">
    <label for="employeeexcellence">Employee Excellence</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field opt">
    <input id="customerexcellence" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Customer Excellence" name="customerexcellence">
    <label for="customerexcellence">Customer Excellence</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field opt">
    <input id="Innovation" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Innovation" name="Innovation">
    <label for="Innovation">Innovation</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field opt">
    <input id="Transformation" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Transformation" name="Transformation">
    <label for="Transformation">Transformation</label>
  </div>
-->
```

Comment: @gaby If [you don't know how to edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35430824/2) don't bother. Why would this be a javascript snippet, also what about the other umpteen spelling mistakes?

Comment: What about your ASP *(`<% %>`)* code?

Comment: @Lankymart do not embarrass yourself mate. Learn the SO tools before throwing insults;)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli What suggested to you this needed to be a code snippet? Do you see any runnable code in there? More like don't embarrass yourself! It shows some HTML which is absolutely pointless! The question isn't complete so how do you expect to show a useful snippet from that?

Answer (score 1):

Selectbox values are submitted with the name of the `select` element.

The `name` attribute on the `option` is not used (*is invalid to be accurate*), so all selected values are submitted as `AwardsSecondaryCatagory`

Comment: How can i restrict the list box to select not more than two values in the html page itself

Comment: @DineshKumarSingh Answer is bang on, but this isn't the place to start asking follow on questions, encourage you to read [ask] before posting more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover you data just by:

```
<%
AwardsSecondaryCatagory = request("AwardsSecondaryCatagory")
%>
```

and, then, just store it in your database!